# Должен ли ndk-build требовать .o файл?

Tags: android-ndk, so

Пытаюсь пересобрать SoLoud в .so-файл. В [репозитории](https://github.com/jarikomppa/soloud) уже есть инструменты для сборки под определённые платформы, я собираю под Android. Запускаю ndk-build в той же папке, где лежат Android.mk и Application.mk. В итоге, получается следующий вывод:

```
Android NDK: android-10 is unsupported. Using minimum supported version android-19.
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soloud-android <= main.cpp
error: unable to open output file 'D:/Fifth/Desktop/Templates/SoLoud/soloud_20200207/demos/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/soloud-android/main.o':
  'No such file or directory'
1 error generated.
make: *** [D:/nonascii/android-ndk-r25c/build/../build/core/build-binary.mk:424: D:/Fifth/Desktop/Templates/SoLoud/soloud_20200207/demos/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/soloud-android/main.o] Error 1
```

Возможно, надо было бы написать это в issues (перевод из головы вылетел) самого репозитория, но на всякий случай сначала спросил здесь, потому что, как мне кажется, я просто что-то неправильно делаю.
Так вот: что я неправильно делаю?